# How to shuffle dynamic object of associative array to get to this combination

Tags: php, laravel

how to shuffle multiple associative array objects to get to this combinations ?

[I have this objects here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vs1Vu.png) 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lh5T.png)

[I want t get to this combination](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyBLu.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB1vZ.png)

```
foreach($placeHolders2 as $key => $value) {
    foreach($value as $key2 => $value2) {
        for($i=0 ; $i< count(collect($value2)); $i++) {
            info($value2[$i]);
        }
    }
}
```

[the code above gives this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15YSL.png)

the data is something like this :

```
[2023-05-18 15:01:24] local.INFO: array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'shapes',
    'values' => 
    array (
      0 => '',
      1 => '',
      2 => '',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'hearts',
    'values' => 
    array (
      0 => '❤',
      1 => '',
      2 => '',
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'fruits',
    'values' => 
    array (
      0 => '',
      1 => '',
      2 => '',
    ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to also print the other values. Currently, you're only printing the inner elements. Also, the given structure is not hierarchical, so you have to do it a little different. I don't have laravel, so I use `echo` instead of `info`. You can change this.
You would want to loop over the flat structure, but build a hierarchical structure from this. So we are looping several times over the same inner arrays, to print all combinations.

**UPDATE**

To print chains with arbitrary length, you have to do this recursively. I've updated the code to do this. Basically it's a tree traversal, which is collecting all the nodes to the leaf and print it as the full path, since this is, what actually want.

```php
<?php

$data = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'shapes',
    'values' => 
    array (
      0 => '',
      1 => '',
      2 => '',
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'hearts',
    'values' => 
    array (
      0 => '❤',
      1 => '',
      2 => '',
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'name' => 'fruits',
    'values' => 
    array (
      0 => '',
      1 => '',
      2 => '',
    ),
  ),
);  

getChainedOutput($data, 0, []);

function getChainedOutput(array $arr, int $i, array $ans) {
    foreach($arr[$i]['values'] as $key => $value) {
        array_push($ans, $value);
        if (false === isset($arr[$i + 1])) {
            echo printChain($ans);
        } else {
            getChainedOutput($arr, $i + 1, $ans);
        }
        array_pop($ans);
        if ($i == 0) {
            echo '-------------------------' . PHP_EOL;
        }
    }
}

function printChain($path) {
    return implode(' --> ', $path) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Will produce

```php
 --> ❤ --> 
 --> ❤ --> 
 --> ❤ --> 
 -->  --> 
 -->  --> 
 -->  --> 
 -->  --> 
 -->  --> 
 -->  --> 
-------------------------
 --> ❤ --> 
 --> ❤ --> 
 --> ❤ --> 
 -->  --> 
 -->  --> 
 -->  --> 
 -->  --> 
 -->  --> 
 -->  --> 
-------------------------
 --> ❤ --> 
 --> ❤ --> 
 --> ❤ --> 
 -->  --> 
 -->  --> 
 -->  --> 
 -->  --> 
 -->  --> 
 -->  --> 
-------------------------
```

Comment: Sorry but I forgot to mention that the number of clusters may vary example Shapes, fruist, cars,....

Comment: I've updated the answer to meet the new requirements. Not sure, if you got a notification.